# F# overloading operators for generic types

Tags: generics, f#, mono, operator-overloading, inline

I'm trying to define a module containing a generic type with operator overloading, but the mono compiler seems to ignore my types in the implementation file. My interface file looks like:

```
module Vector
[<Sealed>]
type Vector<'a> =
  static member ( +. ) : Vector<'a> * Vector<'a> -> Vector<'a>
val make : 'a * 'a -> Vector<'a>
val coord : Vector<'a> -> 'a * 'a
```

And my implementation is

```
module Vector
type Vector<'a> =
  | V of 'a * 'a
  static member ( +. ) (V(x1,y1), V(x2,y2)) = V(x1+x2, y1+y2)
let make (x, y) = V(x, y)
let coord (V(x, y)) = (x, y)
```

When I compile I get:

```
fsharpc -a VectorParam.fsi VectorParam.fs
F# Compiler for F# 3.1 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

/.../VectorParam.fs(4,19): error FS0034: Module 'Vector' contains
    static member Vector.( +. ) : Vector<int> * Vector<int> -> Vector<int>    
but its signature specifies
    static member Vector.( +. ) : Vector<'a> * Vector<'a> -> Vector<'a>    
The types differ
```

which I don't understand, since I'm using a tagged type. And, if I remove all "<'a>" and replace remaining type aliases with float, then everything works fine. Can anyone help me understand the right syntax?

Thanks, Jon

Comment: Just an FYI, fsharpc (fsc.exe) is distrubuted by Xamarin with Mono, but it comes from http://fsharp.org / https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp which is the xplat version that comes from MS (https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp)

Answer (score 8):

I would start by ditching the fsi file - it is not really required.  If you really need it, the easiest way to create it is by pasting your file into fsi and copying the output, or you can get the compiler to generate one for you.

When doing type inference over numeric types it is best to use inline members.  The reason is that F# really likes to use int - and as soon as it sees a `+` with no further constraints the compiler will infer `int`.  This is because in the .NET type system, not all of the constraints used by F# can be expressed.  Using `inline` bypasses this.

Here is a simple example that can be pasted straight into fsi:

```
type Vector<'a> =
  | V of 'a * 'a
  static member inline ( +. ) (V(x1,y1), V(x2,y2)) = V(x1+x2, y1+y2);;

V(1,1) +. V(1,1);;
V(1.,1.) +. V(1.,1.);;
```

Comment: A quick Google search shows a number of pages about "statically resolved type parameters" and how they allow duck typing. A good blog outlining it can be found at: http://theburningmonk.com/2011/12/f-inline-functions-and-member-constraints/

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to static typing. I'm studying module building in fsharp via the mono implementation on a mac, and I really like the idea of specifying an interface. Using inline together with static typing on ( + ) makes the module build without compile error, but that gives me a new error, when using the library: "The value '( +. )' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not sufficiently accessible". I assume that this means, that inline and module don't mix. So I'm stuck again. Thanks.

Comment: @JonSporring - because inline effectively works by text substitution, the functions you use need to be accessible to the calling code.